# How can I incorporate Scala program into web page

Tags: html, scala, applet

How can I embed a scala project into a website ? I did a visual with swing but I have no idea on how to make it inside my web page and have button, textfield, etc functional.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Scala is available with JS backend. Take a look to https://www.lihaoyi.com/hands-on-scala-js/

Comment: Yeah, I read the page, but it's more like creating a web page from scala. What I would want is to make a scala program usable inside a container in a web page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to package your scala program into a jar and use any supported library from the webpage to call the jar(ex: subprocess/Jython library for Django)